# Modify URL Of the my profile tabs (overview, ... , ... )when mysite is created

Tags: 2010, my-site, configuration, custom

I would like to modify the URL of my profile tabs (Overview, content, Tags and Notes...) when the mysite is created.

Initially, If Person A Clicks on MySite it is going to create Person A MYSite and i should see the modified URL's of the tabs... How can i achieve this ?

Comment: The URL is based on the page name and the location of the MySite Host.  What kind of modification are you looking for?  You can change the URL by changing the location, is this the change you are looking for?

Comment: Yes it is a bit unclear exactly what your question is. Could you try to make it a bit clearer what you want to achieve?

Comment: Ok.  Here is the question again.  I would like to modify the OOB URL's to my custom URL's on the person.aspx page.  I can do using OOB, but i would like to do programatically using feature stapler. Why i am using as a feature stapler is, this would be applicable for newly created sites.  I created a feature stapler, but it is not working... anybody has any idea... ?